# Display a map (google) within a marker infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker, infowindow

I try to display a small map within a google map infowindow. The purpose is once the user click on the marker, an infowindow opens with a small map in it displaying the satellite view. The main code below is working quite well. The only thing is that I have an empty 'map_loc' because I don't know where to put the 'var map_loc'.

I'm using a query in a while loop from a mysql database to get the informations required.

Basically my question is, where do I have to put that portion of code in the main code below to display the small map named 'map_loc' which the div is in the marker 'locations':

```
var map_loc = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_loc'), {
  zoom: 17,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlng_loc?>),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});
```

-

```
<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:600px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
<?php
        while ($x = $req->fetch())
        {
        // variables obtained :
        $name = $d['name'];
        $latlng_loc = $d['latlng']; // I need it to display the marker at the good location but also now to display the map within the infowindow
        ?>
        ['<h3><?php echo $name;?></h3><div id="loc_map" style="width:250px; height:150px;"></div>', <?php echo $latlng_loc?>],<?php
        }
?>
];

// here is the main map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlng?>),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

infowindow of google map, It can be use HTML intent .. try this:
example to 1 marker:

```
var content1 = '<div id="smallmap1"></div>';
var map_loc;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {
  infowindow.setContent(content1);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  set_small_map(i);
}
})(marker, i));

//"smallmap"+i == smallmap1, if i == 1;
function set_small_map(i){
     map_loc = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("smallmap"+i), {
     zoom: 17,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlng_loc?>),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
     });
};
```